# Saving variables in AnyLogic

Tags: database, excel, variables, save, anylogic

In AnyLogic, how can I save the variables into an excel file automatically after every time I run the simulation? I have created a dataset associating with the same variable (because variables are not saved in Log, so I used dataset) and I can read it in the Log after running the simulation, but I need to save it automatically in excel file, so each time I don't need to copy the table from Log and paste it to excel.
I tried to use the database to store the variables but it seems too complicated and I couldn't work with it!

Answer (score 0):

There are three ways:

1. Save the variable/dataset values into custom database table with [INSERT query](https://help.anylogic.com/topic/com.xj.anylogic.help/html/connectivity/Inserting.html), then export the table to Excel with [automatic export feature](https://help.anylogic.com/topic/com.xj.anylogic.help/html/connectivity/Export_Excel.html);
2. Create editable [database view](https://help.anylogic.com/topic/com.xj.anylogic.help/html/connectivity/View.html?resultof=%22editable%22%20%22edit%22%20%22copy%22%20%22copi%22%20) of some Log table (see Creating own logs section [here](https://help.anylogic.com/topic/com.xj.anylogic.help/html/connectivity/Logs.html)), and setup the same automatic export procedure.
3. Write the variable value directly to Excel file with [Excel connectivity tool](https://help.anylogic.com/topic/com.xj.anylogic.help/html/connectivity/Excel_File.html) (old-fashioned way, better to use 1 or 2).